# Why am I getting non-sinusoidal output for sinusoidal input in mass-spring system?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, steady-state

A mass spring system is represented by following transfer function

$$ H(s) = \frac{s^{2} + 0.1s + 10}{s^{4} + 0.2s^{3} + 20s^{2}} $$

but for sinusoidal input I am getting non sinusoidal output as shown below, as per my understanding response of the LTI system to sinusoidal input is sinusoidal[image]

I am using below MATLAB code to generate the plot

```
sys_x1 = tf([1,0.1,10],[1,0.2,20,0,0])    
t = 0:0.1:20;
u = sin(1*t);
lsim(sys_x1, u,t)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that defines `sys_x1`?

Comment: @ErikM Added `sys_x1 = tf([1,0.1,10],[1,0.2,20,0,0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is not stable -- the presence of a pole with zero real part rules out asymptotic stability; the multiplicity of the poles at zero rules out marginal stability. The statement that an LTI system generates a sinusoidal output for a sinusoidal input is only true for *stable* systems.

Comment: Or, more precisely, the output is the superposition of the expected sinusoidal signal and an unstable (unbounded) signal.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for the answer. But in case of unstable system shouldnt the output be something like this picture -> https://deckofpandas.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/sinewave3-part.png

Comment: @Erik "The statement that an LTI system generates a sinusoidal output for a sinusoidal input is only true for stable systems." could you please cite the reference for this statement? Because the books I referred does not mention its not valid for unstable LTI systems.